# Linking to libopengl32.a fails in dev C++

Tags: c++, opengl, compiler-errors, mingw, dev-c++

When I try to compile my first OpenGL program I get the error `cannot find -libopengl32.a` I've included `-lws2_32 -libopengl32 -libglu32 -libglut32` under "add these commands to the linker command line"

EDIT: If there's any other information that you think is relevant such as the code I'm trying to use add it in the comments and I'll add it to the question.

Comment: Well, (1) have you installed the relevant library? and (2) are you using `-static` by chance?

Comment: I don't know what -static is, I highly doubt I'm using it, and I have installed the relevant libraries to c:\dev-cpp\lib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linker "add library" command line options is just `-l…`. It should be

```
-lopengl32 -lglu32 -lglu32 …
```

Not `-lib…`. The linker will automatically prepend a `lib` to the given name.

Comment: It worked but now its giving me 3 other errors,   [Linker error] undefined reference to _imp____glutInitWithExit@12   [Linker error] undefined reference to _imp____glutCreateWindowWithExit@8   [Linker error] undefined reference to _imp____glutCreateMenuWithExit@8

Comment: @user1958850: Well, my above example of course didn't have the glut library added. I thought it was easy to infer the basic scheme from it. You're probably missing a `-lglut32`, because you just copied my line without double checking it.

Comment: @user1958850: Which GLUT version do you use? IIRC glutInitWithExit is part of FreeGLUT and is not present in the old and dusted original, unmaintained GLUT.

Comment: i was using libglut that comes with dev-c++ 4.9.9.2, i have freeGLUT for MingW but I haven't installed it yet, let me see if that fixes it.. EDIT: it worked.

Answer (score 0):

change the glut.h, libglut32.a or .lib and if u want to be more sure...copy glut32.dll file into the "window/system32/"...
it will work....

if not...remove Dec-c++ entirely from ur PC and reinstall it again...newer version ofcourse